# Error code - cannot do apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

The standard software updater says the package system is broken. It while installing updates.

When I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic (4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
initrd.img(/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
) points to /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
 (/boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic.postinst line 491.
vmlinuz(/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
) points to /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
 (/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic) -- doing nothing at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic.postinst line 491.
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-52-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.8.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-52-generic
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 13: /etc/default/grub: intel_idle.max_cstate=1: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic.postinst line 1052.
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-4.8.0-52-generic:
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-52-generic depends on linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic (= 4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1); however:
  Package linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-4.8.0-52-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic
 linux-signed-image-4.8.0-52-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-get -f install` and `dpkg --configure -a` yield the same.

What do I do? I don't have Synaptic installed, and I cannot install anything now.

The contents of `/etc/default/grub` are:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
intel_idle.max_cstate=1 acpi_backlight=vendor


# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I have added the contents of /etc/default/grub.

Comment: I managed to fix it:
https://gist.github.com/zas/205372c824decb8e121baec2f86e1415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in line 13 of `/etc/default/grub`. It looks like its content was supposed to be assigned to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` in the previous line. Here's how to do it correctly:

1. Replace lines 12 and 13 with:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_idle.max_cstate=1 acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
2. Finish the installation of half-installed packages with:

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```

   This will also update the Grub configuration based on the changes in step 1 (which is why it failed in the first place), so there's no need to run `update-grub` again.